# BackPropagation Neuron Network Approach - Design

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation, bias-neuron

I am trying to make a digit recognition program. I shall feed a white/black image of a digit and my output layer will fire the corresponding digit (one neuron shall fire, out of the 0 -> 9 neurons in the Output Layer). I finished implementing a Two-dimensional BackPropagation Neuron Network. My topology sizes are [5][3] -> [3][3] -> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRemJ.png)[10]. So it's One 2-D Input Layer, One 2-D Hidden Layer and One 1-D Output Layer. However I am getting weird and wrong results (Average Error and Output Values).

Debugging at this stage is kind of time consuming. Therefore, I would love to hear if this is the correct design so I continue debugging. Here are the flow steps of my implementation:

- Build the Network: One Bias on each Layer except on the Output Layer (No Bias). A Bias's output value is always = 1.0, however its Connections Weights get updated on each pass like all other neurons in the network. All Weights range 0.000 -> 1.000 (no negatives)
- Get Input data (0 | OR | 1) and set nth value as the nth Neuron Output Value in the input layer.
- Feed Forward: On each Neuron 'n' in every Layer (except the Input Layer):

  - Get result of SUM (Output Value * Connection Weight) of connected Neurons
    from previous layer towards this nth Neuron.
  - Get TanHyperbolic - Transfer Function - of this SUM as Results
  - Set Results as the Output Value of this nth Neuron
- Get Results: Take Output Values of Neurons in the Output Layer
- BackPropagation:

  - Calculate Network Error: on the Output Layer, get SUM Neurons' (Target Values - Output Values)^2. Divide this SUM by the size of the Output Layer. Get its SquareRoot as Result. Compute Average Error = (OldAverageError * SmoothingFactor * Result) / (SmoothingFactor + 1.00)
  - Calculate Output Layer Gradients: for each Output Neuron 'n', nth Gradient = (nth Target Value - nth Output Value) * nth Output Value TanHyperbolic Derivative
  - Calculate Hidden Layer Gradients: for each Neuron 'n', get SUM (TanHyperbolic Derivative of a weight going from this nth Neuron * Gradient of the destination Neuron) as Results. Assign (Results * this nth Output Value) as the Gradient.
  - Update all Weights: Starting from the hidden Layer and back to the Input Layer, for nth Neuron: Compute NewDeltaWeight = (NetLearningRate * nth Output Value * nth Gradient + Momentum * OldDeltaWeight). Then assign New Weight as (OldWeight + NewDeltaWeight)
- Repeat process.

Here is my attempt for digit number seven. The outputs are Neuron # zero and Neuron # 6. Neuron six should be carrying 1 and Neuron # zero should be carrying 0. In my results, all Neuron other than six are carrying the same value (# zero is a sample).

[image: Sample Results]

Sorry for the long post. If you know this then you probably know how cool it is and how large it is to be in a single post. Thank you in advance

Comment: Typically Softmax with log-loss is typically used for multiclass output layer activation function. It is not clear to me if you were doing binary or multiclass output.

Comment: I am a beginner. I don't know the meaning of binary vs multiclass output layer. I provided my goal of this project in the first paragraph. Please read it and provide any feedback. Appreciate it and thanks

Comment: Sure. You have multiclass/multinomial: with the 10 possible digits comprising the 10 classes. So you can try changing your output layer activation function to softmax  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function. Let us know what effect that has.

Comment: I made this an answer in order to put the relevant section in relief.

Comment: Do we need to delete the comments then?

Comment: Not really necessary - i've seen other questions follow this pattern of growing from comments to answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Softmax with log-loss is typically used for multiclass output layer activation function. You have multiclass/multinomial: with the 10 possible digits comprising the 10 classes.

So you can try changing your output layer activation function to softmax

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function

> **Artificial neural networks**
>
> In neural network simulations, the
>   softmax function is often implemented at the final layer of a network
>   used for classification. Such networks are then trained under a log
>   loss (or cross-entropy) regime, giving a non-linear variant of
>   multinomial logistic regression.

Let us know what effect that has. –

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Q: if I have 10 Neurons (each shall carry 0 or 1) is't still considered 10 classes? Indeed 10 digits but each Neuron has one of two possible values. I took a look on Softmax, another Q: Should I create another class of Neurons (to carry this different transfer method) then create an Output Layer containing such objects? Or same class but add a second transfer function should be fine? Thanks again.

Comment: Just replace tanh activation function with softmax *only on the output layer*. The tanh is reasonable for the input to hidden and hidden to hidden layers. Re: 10 neurons - yes that is what I said that you do have ten classes.

Comment: Working on it. I also decided to build the XOR instead of my goal, for testing/learning/simplifying the Neuron Network. Thank you